# Elasticsearch query MUST conditions with MUST NOT

Tags: elasticsearch, conditional-statements

Given a customer purchase order elasticsearch index, I want to query for records under ALL the following criteria

- `purchase_datetime` field greater than a specified date.
- `product_name` field in a wildcard search.
- `customer_id` NOT equal to a list of ids.

Here is an example query that I've tried:

```
{"query": {
           "bool": {
                    "must": [
                             {"range": {"purchase_datetime": {"gte": "2022-01-01"}}},
                             {"wildcard": {"product_name": {"value": "*iphone*"}}}
                             ],
                    "must_not": [
                                 {"terms": {"customer_id":["id1", "id2"]}}
                                 ]
                    }
           }
}
```

I've tried variations of the above query and either I get "invalid query" or it doesn't seem to filter out customer_ids specified in the `must_not` query.

Comment: Could you please run query [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/search-explain.html) against one of the docs that should be filtered out? Also, share relevant parts of the mapping (including the fields you use).

Comment: what is type of `customer_id` field ? is it object, nested, or keywrod ?